# OAuth Application Identity extension class

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm new to OAuth and its app identity method. I use **app identity** to access an API using OAuth. I found a tutorial [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon/).
In the [source code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon), since both web application and API will be using AAD, why does it not have `AADAuthenticationExtensions.cs` and `AADOptions.cs` classes?

Comment: It is using ADAL library to handle the OAuth. Here is the the client credential flows.https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an asp.net sampe which uses ADAL library to obtain the access token. [Here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows) is the the client credential flows.

The `AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.cs` and `AzureAdOptions.cs` apply to ASP.NET Core and you find the sample [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/).

Comment: So for asp.net core, I will use the extensions class to enable app identity flow?

Comment: Yes, asp.net and asp.net core use different class library. But they are all use the openid connect middlerware to auth. You can find the principle here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code